# Debug an Eclipse plugin in a different language?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, internationalization

I'm trying to debug an Eclipse plug-in when it is running in another language (japanese).

The problem I'm encountering is: I can't get the Eclipse debugger to run another Eclipse instance in another language.

I've got all my strings externalized to resource bundles ... and, when the plug-in is installed in Eclipse on a machine that has it's default language set to Japanese, it runs OK ... but there are a few problems that I need to resolve.

I've tried setting the Eclipse -nl parameter to ja_JP along with '-Duser.language=ja -Duser.country=JP' on the VM arguments, but every time Eclipse is launched, everything is in English.

Any suggestions on how I can get the debugger to launch the Eclipse instance in Japanese?

Comment: FWIW: I'm running on WinXP with the IBM J9 JVM and Eclipse 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

David: Try this. In eclipse.ini add the below line:

> -nl
>   ja_JP

Where ja_JP stands for the Japanese langaguage locale. Remove Internationalization specific parameters from 'VM arguments' and 'Program Arguments'  (In the Arguments tab of the launch configuration).

Your Japanese properties file should end with XXX_ja_JP.properties

Answer (score 0):

You should give the -nl parameter in the Program arguments, not VM args. (In the Arguments tab of the launch configuration)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did ... the -nl arg was on the program arguments, the various -D properteis on the VM arguments.